# How do I declare a static variable as a reference to a hard-coded memory address?

Tags: rust, embedded, ffi

I am working on embedded Rust code for LPC82X series controllers from NXP - the exact toolchain does not matter for the question.

These controllers contain peripheral drivers in ROM. I want to use these drivers, which means I need to use unsafe Rust and FFI without linking actual code.

The ROM APIs expose function pointers packed into C structs at specific address locations. If somebody wants the details of this API, chapter 29 of [the LPC82X manual](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10800.pdf) describes the API in question.

My Rust playground dummy sketch looks like this, that would be hidden from application code, by a yet unwritten I2C abstraction lib. This compiles.

```
#![feature(naked_functions)]

const I2C_ROM_API_ADDRESS: usize = 0x1fff_200c;
static mut ROM_I2C_API: Option<&RomI2cApi> = None;

#[repr(C)]
struct RomI2cApi {
    // Dummy functions, real ones take arguments, and have different return
    // These won't be called directly, only through the struct's implemented methods
    // value
    master_transmit_poll: extern "C" fn() -> bool,
    master_receive_poll: extern "C" fn() -> bool,
}

impl RomI2cApi {
    fn api_table() -> &'static RomI2cApi {
        unsafe {
            match ROM_I2C_API {
                None => RomI2cApi::new(),
                Some(table) => table,
            }
        }
    }

    unsafe fn new() -> &'static RomI2cApi {
        ROM_I2C_API = Some(&*(I2C_ROM_API_ADDRESS as *const RomI2cApi));
        ROM_I2C_API.unwrap()
    }

    #[inline]
    fn master_transmit_poll(&self) -> bool {
        (self.master_transmit_poll)()
    }

    #[inline]
    fn master_receive_poll(&self) -> bool {
        (self.master_receive_poll)()
    }
}

impl From<usize> for &'static RomI2cApi {
    fn from(address: usize) -> &'static RomI2cApi {
        unsafe { &*(address as *const RomI2cApi) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let rom_api = unsafe { RomI2cApi::api_table() };
    println!("ROM I2C API address is: {:p}", rom_api);
    // Should be commented out when trying !
    rom_api.master_transmit_poll();
}
```

I cannot declare the function pointer structs as non-mutable static as statics have many restrictions, including not dereferencing pointers in the assignment. Is there a better workaround than `Option`? Using `Option` with the `api_table` function at least guarantees that initialization happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>You can get around having a static at all:</strike>

```
const ROM_I2C_API: &RomI2cApi = &*(0x1fff_200c as *const RomI2cApi);
```

Not yet working, but is planned to work in the future. For now use

```
const ROM_I2C_API: *const RomI2cApi = 0x1fff_200c as *const RomI2cApi;

fn api_table() -> &'static RomI2cApi {
    unsafe { &*(ROM_I2C_API) }
}
```

This creates a `&'static RomI2cApi` and allows you to access the functions everywhere directly by calling `api_table().master_transmit_poll()`

Comment: That one won't work as const initialization has the same restriction as static init - error[E0396]: raw pointers cannot be dereferenced in constants However this works
    
    const ROM_I2C_API2: *const RomI2cApi = 0x1fff_200c as *const RomI2cApi;

Comment: oh... sorry about that. I was so used to it working I forgot it's not working yet. Should be in stable rustc in 3 months or so: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/46882

Comment: Thanks, I think I will settle with that.
Naked most likely won't work in my case, but I hope compiler will do its best to optimize out the call chain.

Comment: Also, thanks for the info on rust feature update, I am accepting the answer partly because of this!